# npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user on Mac

Tags: npm, npm-install

I am trying to run the the command `npm install -y` but I keep getting the following error...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqFq0.png)

I've tried to run `sudo npm install -y` but that hasn't gotten me anywhere. Any ideas?

The error message says that may need to run as root/admin but I'm pretty sure that I'm running as the admin. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should not be running npm under `sudo`. Instead you need to make sure that your directory and all sub-directories are writable by you.

To be safe, I would delete your current install, and restart in a directory where you know the current user has write permissions.

If you can't do that, then run the following command to make sure that your user has permission to write (be aware that this will not work if you don't have `su` access on your machine in the directory you are in:

```
sudo chown -R <youruser>:<youruser> *
sudo chmod -R u+w *
```

Be careful since this will change ownership and permissions on all files in the subtree (except for files beginning with `.`).

Comment: Hey man! Really appreciate this! Learned a lot about permissions etc. from trying to figure this out!